# Unable to intercept ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot

I need to set some system properties programmatically and I figured that the best way would be doing it in the event listener once `ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent` was intercepted.
But the problem is that I am not able to catch that event in my listener.

```
@Component
public class AppListener {

    @EventListener
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent event) {
        if (event instanceof ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent) {
            System.setProperty("java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.threadFactory", MyThreadFactory.class.getName());
        }
    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong and why I cannot catch that event?

Answer (score 16):

From the [Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-spring-application.html#boot-features-application-events-and-listeners):

> Some events are actually triggered before the ApplicationContext is
>   created, so you cannot register a listener on those as a @Bean. You
>   can register them with the SpringApplication.addListeners(…​) method
>   or the SpringApplicationBuilder.listeners(…​) method.

And from the [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/event/EventListener.html) (this for version 5.1.7):

> Processing of @EventListener annotations is performed via the internal
>   EventListenerMethodProcessor bean which gets registered automatically
>   when using Java config or manually via the
>    or element when
>   using XML config.

So ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent (and all of the Spring Boot application events) occur before context and bean creation, and @EventListener is controlled by a bean, so the @EventListener annotation cannot be picked up at this point.  You will have to specifically create a listener class and add it explicitly to capture this event (or any event that occurs before bean creation).

Your class:

```
public class AppListener implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent>
{
    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent event)
    {
        System.setProperty("java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.threadFactory",
                MyThreadFactory.class.getName());
    }
}
```

...and the relevant SpringApplicationBuilder code:

```
ConfigurableApplicationContext context = new SpringApplicationBuilder(Launcher.class)
            .listeners(new AppListener()).run();
```

Comment: I have this setup but i do have a problem with `spring.jpa` and `datasource`. 
When I run the application using the embedded tomcat, the listener works as expected and properties are filled from aws but when i deploy the war to the tomcat, it does not call this listener and it goes directly to contextinitialization and after that `datasource`, and since datasource properties are not filled, i get exception on the jpa initialization step. what is the problem with this listener and tomcat?

Answer (score -3):

You need implement ApplicationListener interface for this event specifically

```
@Component
public class AppListener implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationEvent> {

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent event) {
        if (event instanceof ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent) {
            System.setProperty("java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.threadFactory", MyThreadFactory.class.getName());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: @Compoent creates bean and it definitely managed in IOC, not before it .